# The number of 0-1 normal matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ be a $n\times n $ matrix with entries in the discrete set $\{0,1\}$.

> **My question:** What is the number of matrices in $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ that are normal, that is, that satisfy $AA^\top-A^\top A=0$?

If we restrict the attention to the subclass of symmetric matrices, my question becomes quite trivial. However, the extension to the whole class of normal matrices seems quite involved. In particular, I would like to know if this problem has already been studied in the literature.

---

**EDIT.** [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A055547) has a page dedicated to this problem, as pointed out by @Wojowu in a comment. However, only a (trivial) lower bound (in terms of the number of symmetric matrices) is listed.

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A055547)

Comment: @Wojowu Posting just this link is not very informative. Well, there is an entry in OEIS about these numbers, but is there any research about it? (Answer: The OEIS page does not give any links to literature (except  general references), so it's not clear.)

Comment: @Dirk That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sure, and a good one. Just saying that adding "There is an entry in..." would have been an even better comment.

Comment: What about normal matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$? Is this known?

Comment: For a binary normal matrix $A$, one may consider the orbit $\mathcal{O}_A:=\{P^TAP: P \text{ a permutation matrix}\}$. What is a convenient choice for a "special form" (a representant)  in  $\mathcal{O}_A$? One could then try to count the number of these "special forms", and then sum the cardinality of the orbits of each special form.

Comment: @PietroMajer Considering $A$ to be the adjacency matrix of a digraph (allowing loops), this is usual isomorphism of digraphs. This could be used to extend the OEIS table by at least two more values, but I don't see how it would help in general.  Incidentally such digraphs (perhaps without loops) are unsurprisingly called "normal digraphs".

Answer (score 6):

For orders 1 to 9:

2, 8, 68, 1124, 36112, 2263268, 281249824, 70329901860, 35546752694048.

I computed these numbers by finding representatives of the isomorphism classes of normal digraphs plus the size of each isomorphism class.

I don't know of any enumeration results for general order, even asymptotics.

Richard Stanley asked about normal matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and Martin Rubey gave the first four values in the comments below. The same method works there but is more expensive because the conditions are weaker.  Here are the first eight values:

2, 8, 80, 1472, 56192, 3934208, 557649920, 154665746432

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the first few values for matrices over $\mathbb F_2$ are $2,8,80,1472$.

Comment: @MartinRubey  Interesting.  I'm thinking that my computation method (using isomorph-free generation of digraphs) might be able to work for that case too, though probably not as far.  Are there operations other than $A\mapsto P^TAP$ for permutation matrix $P$ that preserve normality?

Comment: For $\mathbb F_2$, the inverse (if it exists) also preserves normality, and is not necessarily conjugation by a permutation matrix.

Comment: @MartinRubey See my additions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is still open. See here - https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02842

Comment: Very interesting paper.  But how does one go from the $\pm 1$ case to the 0-1 case?